# Should offline users of an online video game be forced to accept ToS?

Tags: terms-of-service

In the context of a video game that has online and offline play.

An account is needed to play online, but no account is required to play offline.

Assuming the user must accept some terms while signing up, is it necessary to show a legal document for a user only playing offline?

The game also uses CC 3.0 licensed assets.

Are these valid reasons to create some terms the user must accept while playing offline? Could both online and offline documents be merged into one that the user must accept in the first launch of the game?

Answer (score 3):

"Terms of Service" implies that you are providing a *service*.  If it's offline, you probably aren't doing that.

You can still have a license agreement that applies.  If certain types of CC licenses are involved, you may even be required to.

Answer (score 0):

Your TOS can have terms which only app!y to online play.

For instance Diablo II was open and moddable, and some wonderful mods came out of that.  Blizzard didn't care what you did in single-player or LAN play.  However in online play (battle.net not LAN), you are not allowed to mod the game at all, obviously!